# WebStorm file watcher does not work after Mac update

Tags: sass, webstorm, file-watcher

This is the current settings:

- Arguments: `$FileName$ $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --source-map true --output-style expanded`
- Output paths to refresh : `$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

It's coming out like this. Why is that?

> `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass aaa.scss /Users/aaa/WebstormProjects/aaa/css/aaa.css --source-map true --output-style expanded`
> env: node: No such file or directory
>
> Process finished with exit code 127

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"node: No such file or directory"* -- the system does not see your `node` executable. 1) Do you have it? 2) Will it work if you execute `node` in WebStorm's built-in terminal? 3) Will it work if you launch WebStorm from your OS terminal (i.e. `open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app/` kind of line)?

Comment: The same on WebStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5526028407826-webstorm-filewatcher-does-not-work-after-Mac-mony-update

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling the MacOS.